# Как открыть телефонную книгу на телефоне пользователя в телефон при клике на кнопку React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку, у пользователя открывалось приложение Телефон с уже введенным номером. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В теории это сработает <a href=”tel:+79999999999”>+7(999)999-99-99</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо ссылку у кнопки сделать с адресом: `tel:89000000000`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#built-in-url-schemes